# How to know the rule number from which reduction occured in ply?

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, ply

Suppose I have the following rules in my grammar. I want to know from which rule reduction is occurring.

```
iteration_statement : WHILE push_scope LPAREN expression  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope 
                           | DO push_scope compound_statement WHILE LPAREN expression  RPAREN  SEMICOLON pop_scope 
                           | FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement expression SEMICOLON expression  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope 
                           | FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement SEMICOLON expression  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope 
                           | FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement expression SEMICOLON  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope 
                           | FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement SEMICOLON  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope
```

I want to do something like this

```py
if p.ruleno==1:
   #action for while
elif p.ruleno==2:
  # action for do while
elif p.ruleno==3:
    # action for for in rule 3
elif p.ruleno==4:
   # action for for in rule 4
elif p.ruleno==5:
    # action for for in rule 5
elif p.ruleno==6:
   # action for for in rule 6
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you always require a compound statement for `for` loops (but not while or do-while loops), except if both expressions have been left out? Or is that a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how Ply works. Put each production in its own function:

```
def p_iter_1(p):
    '''iteration_statement : WHILE push_scope LPAREN expression  RPAREN  statement pop_scope'''
     # Do action 1

def p_iter_2(p):
    '''iteration_statement : DO push_scope statement WHILE LPAREN expression  RPAREN  SEMICOLON pop_scope''''
    # Do action 2

def p_iter_3(p):
    '''iteration_statement : FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement expression SEMICOLON expression  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope'''
    # Do action 3

# Etc.
```

The parser associates a reduction function with each production. If you put more than one production in the docstring for a reduction function, that function will be associated with each production. That's fine, if the action is the same. (And they don't even need to reduce to the same non-terminal.) But if the actions are different, the easiest solution is to use different functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the different types of loops into different functions:

```
def p_while(p):
    'iteration_statement : WHILE push_scope LPAREN expression  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope'
    #action for while

def p_do_while(p):
    'iteration_statement : DO push_scope compound_statement WHILE LPAREN expression  RPAREN  SEMICOLON pop_scope'
    #action for do while

def p_for(p):
    'iteration_statement : FOR LPAREN push_scope for_init_statement expression_opt SEMICOLON expression_opt  RPAREN  compound_statement pop_scope'
    # action for for
```

Note: I've simplified your rule for `for` loops to only have a single case (with optional expressions), so you can handle `for` loops in a single method without having to somehow check which of the four alternatives was matched.